# Fail to extract the date from the timestamp by using as.date and if.else

Tags: r, timestamp, data-extraction

I have read a csv file in as mydata,  an existing column called inbound_date, contain the data like

> NULL
>
> 2017-06-24 16:47:35
>
> 2017-06-24 16:47:35

I want to create a new column to extract the day for this column. i have tried below code, but failed,

`mydata$inbound_day<-ifelse(is.null(mydata$inbound_date),"null",as.Date(mydata$inbound_date,format = "%Y-%m-%d"))`

The new column inbound_day has been added, but it shows as NA in the column for all the rows.

Can help to see the code, which part is wrong? Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are two things at play here.

1. The behaviour of `ifelse`. It will return as many values as the
   length of the condition. If the condition returns only one value, `ifelse`
   too will return a single value.
2. The behaviour of `is.null` is not the same as that of `is.na`. Unlike `is.na`,  `is.null(mydata$inbound_date)` is checking the whole
   of `mydata$inbound_date1` as a single object and you are getting
   just one value in return, which is `False`

.

The combined effect of these two things is that you are only getting the `as.Date` value for the first item as result, and it is a single `NA`. What's more, this `NA is then being recycled to fill the whole column with NAs.

Solution -- Use `is.na` where you are using `is.null`. It will return multiple values and the thing will work as expected.

Answer (score 0):

You have to specify the time as well.

```
x <- as.POSIXlt("2017-06-24 16:47:35", format = "%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S")

format(x, "%Y-%m-%d")
[1] "2017-06-24"
```

Answer (score 0):

Using `lubridate` to format instead of as.date then extracting the day

```
library(lubridate)
x <- ymd_hms("2017-06-24 16:47:35")
format(x, "%d")
```